# Why does StateHasChanged() not work on children, but changing the Value does?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

My question is why does one set of code cause all child components to re-render, but the other code, even with a call to `StateHasChanged()` does not. This is pretty simple but I'm starting with the page as a picture is worth 1,000 (or 1.000 for our European friends) words.

[image]

The page is a list of event card components. In the event card component is a tag and organization component. The little hearts are to (un)follow an item. You click on a heart and it changes if you, as the logged in user, are following that tag/organization.

When the click occurs, in the main page code behind, I have updated the list of the objects that are assigned, one per event card, to the displayed cards. All that has changed on a click is the user's list of tags/orgs they are following.

This code will cause all event cards to re-render:

```
var listModels = new List<EventPageViewModel>();
foreach (var eventOn in EventData)
{
    var model = new EventPageViewModel(eventOn);
    model.RefreshUser(User);
    listModels.Add(model);
}
EventData = listModels;
```

This code does not cause any re-rendering other than the specific card that was clicked on:

```
foreach (var modelOn in EventData)
    modelOn.RefreshUser(User);
StateHasChanged();
```

The code `var model = new EventPageViewModel(eventOn);` is a very simple shallow copy constructor. I understand how that shallow copy constructor causes a re-render as the `Value=` for each event card will be passed a new object in that it has a new reference address.

What I don't understand is why `StateHasChanged()` doesn't accomplish the equivalent. Does StateHasChanged only re-render the razor file it is called for and does not force a StateHasChanged on its child components? And if so, is there a way to force a StateHasChanged on the child components other than passing a new `Value=` (via a copy constructor) to the child components?

Comment: What parameters does each event card have assigned?  Are you using @key?

Answer (score 0):

Without any code I can only provide a generic answer.

When a component renders, the renderer checks the parameters assigned to each child component to determine if a component's parameters have changed.  If they have, it calls `SetParametersAsync` on the component, passing in an updated `ParameterView` object.

The code that the Renderer uses to detect a parameter change is :

```cs
public static bool MayHaveChanged<T1, T2>(T1 oldValue, T2 newValue)
{
    var oldIsNotNull = oldValue != null;
    var newIsNotNull = newValue != null;

    // Only one is null so different
    if (oldIsNotNull != newIsNotNull)
        return true;

    var oldValueType = oldValue!.GetType();
    var newValueType = newValue!.GetType();

    // HERE
    if (oldValueType != newValueType)
        return true;

    if (!IsKnownImmutableType(oldValueType))
        return true;

    return !oldValue.Equals(newValue);
}

private static bool IsKnownImmutableType(Type type)
    => type.IsPrimitive
        || type == typeof(string)
        || type == typeof(DateTime)
        || type == typeof(Type)
        || type == typeof(decimal)
        || type == typeof(Guid);
```

If the code you've shown is in a UI event in the parent [button click or ...] then calling `StateHasChanged` will have no effect.  The UI event handler will call it anyway.

Comment: That explains why `Value=list` doesn't re-render when I change `list[5]=newValue` because it just tests to see if the list reference value has changed and it has not. That's reasonable. What I don't understand is why `StateHasChanged()` does not cause the child components that have `Value=enumeratedInstanceFromList` to re-render. If list changing causes the children to re-render, why doesn't StateHasCHanged cause them to re-render? And how can I get them to re-render other than be copying list toa new list and assigning it?

Comment: Can you produce a [mre] to demonstrate the problem.  I'm a bit lost without more code for the context.  There will be a perfectly valid reason.

Comment: Creating a MRE of this would be a couple of hours - it's complicated. What I'm doing is `Value=OrgData` and so after I updated the changed items in OrgData, I have the following line of code `OrgData = new List<OrganizationPageModel>(OrgData);` and that resolves the problem. (It's a small list.) I think what's happening with this is assigning a new list to OrgData tells the page that the `Value=` has changed so re-render as needed. And when it assigns the `Value=` for the child components in the list, the changed ones will also be a new `Value=` and so they re-render.

Comment: StateHasChanged will not render all sub-components regardless.  It will only call SetPatametersAsync on components where it detects a change as per the above detection code.